# Laravel Volt получение id route

Tags: php, laravel

Как получить CategoryID в livewire?

В обычном Route::get работает - "public function createTopic($categoryId): void", а как это делается здесь?

`Volt::route('forum/cat{categoryId}/create', 'pages.forum.topic')->name('forum.topic');`

```
new #[Layout('layouts.app')] class extends Component {
    public string $name = '';

    public function createTopic(): void
    {
        $validated = $this->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'max:255']
        ]);

        $topic = ForumTopicModel::create([
            'name' => $validated['name'],
            'category' => $categoryId,
            'author' => Auth::id()
        ]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это делается аналогично.

В роутах:

```
Volt::route('forum/cat/{categoryId}/create', 'pages.forum.topic')->name('forum.topic');
```

В компоненте:

```
public int $categoryId;
```

В методах компонента используем

```
$this->categoryId;
```

Также через mount:

```
mount(function (int $categoryId) {

});
```